# How to deal with questions on one's website?

Tags: discussion

The question ["I've created a website"](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/14721/15) popped up; I don't recall it popping up before. So I will ask how we should deal with questions that do, as far as I can tell:

- ask for a critique of a specific website
- ask for general guidelines on how to craft a website, generally
- ask for general guidelines on how to craft a website, specifically about cooking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of this is remotely on topic, and frankly it looks like spam to me.

Edit: It's been binned.  Maybe if it wasn't the very first post from a user who just registered 20 minutes ago, it would have been looked upon more favourably.  Regardless, such "questions" add absolutely no value to any Q&A site.

Even if you could make a case for the subject matter being on topic, that would just make it a candidate for "Too Localized" instead.

If you see anything like this again, especially from a new user, don't hesitate, just flag it as spam.

Comment: Agreed: for the latter two it seemed meant for another site (ie webmasters.se) or like it would generate completely subjective answers since there would be no good way to make for criteria in the question.